# What value will var_dump show that echo will not show?

Tags: php

I was solving a question and got to see this one. I really don't know what it is. Just needed a **one word answer** for the problem.

Comment: echo will only print variable and json encoded strings on the other hand var_dump prints any type of data whether be array, string, objects etc. another differnce is that var_dump also show the data type with length etc while echo  cant

Comment: In one word the only thing I can think of is 'Structure'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What value will var_dump show that echo will not show?

You cannot echo an `array` if you do so it will just print `data type` not the data, you can use `var_dump` to print complete structure and data of an `array`.

```
$array = array(1,2,3);

echo $array; //<----only print the data type

var_dump($array) //<-----print the complete structure
```